# Why I can't get the window title of Edge in python 3

Tags: python, windows-10, microsoft-edge, win32gui

**Why can't i get the window title of Microsoft Edge in Python 3**

*My coding environment： windows10(x86) python3.7*

I want to use win32gui to get the active window title, but I met some problem when I opened Microsoft Edge.

Here is my code:

```py
import win32gui as w
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    titleName = w.GetWindowText(w.GetForegroundWindow())
    print(titleName)
```

As my code said I want to get current active window title after each second.

It's all OK before I opened Microsoft Edge.

When I openes edge, the programme showed an error.

question picture:
[image: question picture]

As the picture said:

The programme can Identify all active windows except Microsoft Edge.

When I opened Microsoft Edge, it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "P:/weather/main.py", line 8, in <module> print(titleName)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u200b' in position 103: illegal multibyte sequence
```

It shows it is a `UnicodeEncodeError`, but there is no strange char in the title.

I don't know why.

I've checked a lot on the internet, but none of can help me fixed it.

Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test with your code and it works fine when opening Edge. I think the issue is related with the title of the website you open in Edge. In the error message, it points out character `\u200b`, that's the cause of the issue.

`\u200b` is an invisible space. For more information, you can refer to this article: [u200b: What it is, and why it messes up your code or data](https://dfarq.homeip.net/u200b-what-it-is-and-why-it-messes-up-your-code-or-data/). You can try to remove `\u200b` using regular expressions when getting the title. You can add this line of code before print the title name:

```
titleName.replace('\u200b','')
```

Comment: I successed with your answer. Thank you very much!